# Layout issue when using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: swift, user-interface, avfoundation

I'm trying to learn AVFoundation basics. For now I'm trying to make the simplest custom camera demo possible. The general scheme is to use `UIView` as a container for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

So I create a previewLayer in the following way:

```
let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
```

As a following I do this:

```
previewLayer?.frame = self.imageView.bounds        
self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
captureSession.startRunning()
```

That's basically it. As a result the captureSession is being run but visually camera preview is misplaced inside the `UIView`. Please, see the picture below
[image: Misplaced camera preview]

However, I almost sure I did everything correctly in the storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]
I'm sorry I don't know what to add since I'm relatively new in swift. Please let me know if i miss any information required to answer.

So the question is what might be the reason for this kind of UI behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set view's content mode:

`previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;`

Answer (score 0):

First, assuming that you are using Autolayout, make sure your constraints are correct for your views in the storyboard. If you're not using Autolayout, I would recommend doing that first before proceeding.

You'll need to set the frame for your `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` after adding it to the `imageView`.

```
previewLayer.frame = self.imageView.layer.bounds
```

I think that should take care of it. If you rotate your device, you may need to update the `size` of the `previewLayer` in your view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested with assign layer.bounds after adding preview layer. It did not work. And yes, I do use autoLayout. I will happy to know if you have any other ideas. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your `imageView` is positioned properly. You can set a breakpoint and inspect it that way. You can also check the `previewLayer` frame as well. You could also use Xcode's Debug/View Debugging.

Comment: OK, will look into that. If any of those works I'll accept your answer. Thanks